# How add a chip antenna for the Bluetooth of the module BCM4339?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna

I have the following concern in a design that I am carrying out. I am working on the development of an electronic prototype that uses as a CPU the module: PICO-IMX6-SD. This module has wifi and Bluetooth connectivity and for this uses the BCM4339 chip of the Broadcom company. But in order to provide this functionality you must connect an external antenna through a ufl connector.
[image]
My device consists of a base PCB which contains a 70-pin hirose connector that allows connection to the module PICO-IMX6-SD, I do not want to add an external antenna to the device for some reasons, but I want to include a chip antenna on my PCB. My question is this: if I add the antenna and I put a ufl connector, then when connecting both ufl connectors through a female-female cable would have Bluetooth connectivity?
Or there is the possibility of potential failures.
In general lines I have not found a design that uses the BCM4339 together with an on board antenna. 
A clearer way to explain this is the following: the Intel company launched the Intel Edison module, it has an on board antenna chip for the Bluetooth connection. This module was discontinued, in the prototype I use this module, but I replaced it with the PICO-IMX6-SD. Now I want to add a chip antenna just like the one the Edison has.
What recommendations do you suggest? I'm thinking of using some Murata chip antenna.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a patch antenna mounted to the inside of whatever enclosure you're putting all of this in?

Comment: if I have considered it, but the implementation must be more careful in order to comply with the transmission in the specific frequency. As I am not a RF specialist, I have left this option as the last alternative, but it is one of the most likely according to what I have researched.

Comment: This isn't really an answerable question - your situation is dictated by the unspecified design details of your module, either it has an alternate antenna path or it does not.  You either need to use what the module vendor intended you to use, discuss alternatives with them, or find an alternative to their module.

Comment: the provider indicates that an external antenna should be used, it is the only detail I have. And communicating directly with them has been impossible for me. So I thought in this way to try to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a switch, so you can select between onboard or external antenna? Like this (or similar): 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. This option has not been considered. Another option that I had in mind was to make the antenna as a track on the base PCB. The prototype that I am implementing is a wearable. I am going to review the datasheet of this chip that you indicate me

Comment: OK, I'm using this in a high volume application with PCB trace antenna or externally connected antenna. Selected by the switch.

Comment: It's not clear how this helps the OP to add a chip antenna. His pre-built module only has a u.fl connector on it.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the original question. So the OP has a fixed module that can't be changed and he needs a chip antenna on it. So the easy answer would be that he needs a DeLoeran with a flux capacitor. The correct answer is that he needs a new PCB designed for a chip antenna, with all the requirements that come with it.